# Is mozilla Firefox designed in QT?

Tags: firefox

I wanted to kwn what did the Developers of mozilla use to design and program mozilla firefox browser...

Can anybody help..

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_Mozilla_platform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_Mozilla_platform)

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla uses its own custom toolkit ([XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL)), with platform-specific skins to make things blend in better with native apps.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla uses various different "backends" that are responsible for the low-level operating system stuff - such as creating and managing top-level windows, providing a file picker dialog, playing sounds. Two such backends exist for Linux: one is [based on GTK2](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/widget/gtk2/), the other [on QT](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/widget/qt/). The official Linux builds use the GTK2 backend however and from what I've heard the QT backend is pretty abandoned.

As to high-level stuff - everything is done in [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL) which is platform-independent. The backend has been mostly abstracted away at this point.